# ISO Date in JavaScript to find data

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, find, isodate

I’m using this en the shell of mongo and it works in an exercise,

```
db.datos.find({"date":{$gte:ISODate("2020-05-06T19:10"),$lte:ISODate("2020-05-06T20:58")}}).pretty();
```

But I’m trying to use it in my JS and i can’t find the way,

```
let pE = await Chat.find({"date":{$gte:ISODate("2020-05-06T19:10"),$lte:ISODate("2020-05-06T20:58")}}).pretty();

console.log(pE);
```

I get the error that system can’t find variable ISODate off course...

I see similar exercises but I’m not able to apply it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let pE = await Chat.find({"date":{$gte:new Date(start.toISOString()),$lte:new Date(end.toISOString())}});
```

Works perfectly. Thanks,